# Delete part of a string from one set of characters to another character

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet that I want to remove some HTML tags.  My problem is that some of the tags are not just simple `<div>` tags, but have extra characters like `<div class="ExternalClassEA74AB3F178E48EDAD3BDE4FC90B1182">` Replace from `<div` until we reach the ending `>` of the tag. How do I replace string parts like this with "".  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a perfect solution, and most likely fail to do what you expect it if you have `<` or `>` as an actual text you want to keep.

It should give you a starting point, and should be able to make some changes to achieve the "perfection".

See the comments for more details:

```vb
Sub htmlStrip()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet Name Here") '<- set sheet name
Dim lRow As Long: lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'get last row
Dim lCol As Long: lCol = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'get last column

Dim arrData As Variant: arrData = ws.Range("A1").Resize(lRow, lCol) 'get the data into an array
Dim R As Long, C As Long, X As Long, Z As Long

Const sS As String = "<" 'html tag start
Const sE As String = ">" 'html tag end

Dim lS As Long, lE As Long, lCnt As Long, lECnt As Long
Dim strTmpS As String, strTmpE As String, strTemp As String, strReplace As String


For R = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData) 'iterate through all rows of data
    For C = LBound(arrData, 2) To UBound(arrData, 2) 'iterate through all columns of data
        lS = InStr(1, arrData(R, C), sS) 'get the location of the first tag
        lE = InStr(1, arrData(R, C), sE) 'get the location of the last tag

        If lS > 0 And lE > 0 Then 'if at least one of each found
            If lE < lS Then lE = InStr(lS + 1, arrData(R, C), sE) 'prevent a case when the first tag is the ending one

            lSCnt = Len(arrData(R, C)) - Len(Replace(arrData(R, C), sS, "")) 'check how many times we have the first tag
            lECnt = Len(arrData(R, C)) - Len(Replace(arrData(R, C), sE, "")) 'check how many times we have the last tag

            Z = WorksheetFunction.Min(lSCnt, lECnt) 'avoid a situation when we have some opening or closing tags, but not the matching ones

            For X = 1 To Z 'iterate through the number of times at least both tags are in
                strReplace = Mid(arrData(R, C), lS, lE - lS + 1) 'get the string to replace
                arrData(R, C) = Replace(arrData(R, C), strReplace, "") 'remove the tag found

                lS = InStr(1, arrData(R, C), sS) 'get the location of the first tag (again)
                lE = InStr(1, arrData(R, C), sE) 'get the location of the last tag (again)

                If lS = 0 Or lE = 0 Then Exit For 'either we reached the end of the loop, or did a multi replace - so exit here
            Next X
        End If
    Next C
Next R

ws.Range("A1").Resize(lRow, lCol).Offset(0, lCol) = arrData 'put the data back on the spreadsheet, at the right of the original data

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi FAB.  Thanks for your help.  I'm getting there, it is finding the strings and the tags, but I'm getting an error on the line "strReplace = Mid(arrData(R, C), lS, lE - lS + 1) 'get the string to replace"  The error  is "Invalid procedure call or argument".  I believe it is the arguments.  When I debug I see IE=367 and IS=437.  I guess that is causing a negative number in the argument?  Any ideas?

Comment: I can imagine the that could only happen if you have > before <... I'll check when I get to a computer.

Comment: @L33TLE I've updated the answer to check for such scenarios, it should be better now.

Comment: Hi FAB.  Can you tell why the code is failing on this html string?  `<li>A defined change (bullet# e, g; Pg.3)</li><li>Managers  (bullet# h, Pg.3). Also, respective  (section 5.0, Pg.3)</li></ul><li><strong style="text-decoration&#58;underline;">Document </strong><span style="text-decoration&#58;underline;"><strong>'Sample Report' </strong></span>&#160;also shows (a training platform)</li></ul><p>The following&#58;</p>`

Comment: it seems like it does not like parenthesizes.  If I take them out it works.  And ideas how to avoid this?  ~<li></li><li></li></ul><li><strong></strong><span><strong>(a training platform)</strong></span></li></ul><p></p>~

Comment: @L33TLE what it doesn't like are the double quotes... i think. Let me have a look at how to fix this.

Comment: Hi FAB. No, it is more strange than that.  This is failing  `<li></li><li></li></ul><li><strong></strong><span><strong>any text here</strong></span></li></ul><p></p>`  This is not `<li></li><li></li></ul><li><strong></strong><span><strong></strong></span></li></ul><p></p>`

Comment: @L33TLE it was a lingering bit of logic that was working with the initial string, so went unnoticed... see the updated, should be fine now.

Comment: Thank you for you answer.  It did exactly as advertised.  I wanted to take this further if you want to help.  This is something many people have asked for.  Instead of just clearing all the tags, I would like to replace certain tags that can be represented in Excel, and purge the one Excel does not have suitable replacement.  Like when there are bullet tags, I would like it to replace with a symbol.  If there is a Strong tag I would like to replace with bold in Excel.  Se what I'm getting at?  I think this code would be very valuable to people how want the Excel sheet to have good formatting.

Comment: @L33TLE immediately after `strReplace = Mid(arrData(R, C), lS, lE - lS + 1)`, you can add a few conditions as per your needs. Something like  `If strReplace = "your tag here" Then arrData(R, C) = Replace(arrData(R, C), strReplace, "your new information here") else...`. Will probably need a bit more logic than that, and if you plan to use `<` and/or `>`, even more logic to handle those, but in simple terms, that's were i would start. If you thinking you might multiple possible combinations, then you should make a list on a separate sheet, matching `old tag` to `new info`, and loop over that.

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub RemoveDivs()
    Dim html$
    html = "Some other text<div class=""ExternalClassEA74AB3F178E48EDAD3BDE4FC90B1182""> and here too"
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Pattern = "<div.*?>": .Global = True
        html = .Replace(html, "")
    End With
    MsgBox html
End Sub
```